# Por qué genera el error Uncaught ReferenceError: actualizarAsistencia is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick,

Tags: funcion

```js
function actualizarAsistencia(idAsistencia) {
    var estadoAsistencia = document.querySelector('input[name="estado_asistencia' + idAsistencia + '"]:checked').value;
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "actualizar_estado.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("idAsistencia=" + idAsistencia + "&estadoAsistencia=" + estadoAsistencia);
}
```

1. Al presionar el botón de actualizar asistencia genera el error, donde dice que no está definida la funcion,
2. he intentado llamar el archivo, así como incrustar el la funcion en este mismo archivo.                                           .               .                                                                                  .                                                                                .                        .                                                                 .

   Actualización de Asistencias

   ```
           <style>

           </style>

       </head>

       <body>
           <br><br>


           <h1>Actualización de Asistencias Tabla Temporal</h1>

           <?php

           // Iniciar sesión
           session_start();
           $idProfesor = $_SESSION['id_profesor'];


           // Obtener los valores de los parámetros
           $idEstudiante = $_POST['idEstudiante'];
           $fechaInicio = $_POST['fechaInicio'];
           $fechaFin = $_POST['fechaFin'];
           $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];

           $consulta = "SELECT a.id_asistencia_temp, e.nombre, e.primer_apellido, e.segundo_apellido, m.nombre AS nombre_materia, a.fecha_asistencia, a.hora_asistencia, a.leccion, a.estado_asistencia
           FROM asistencias_temp a
           INNER JOIN estudiantes e ON a.id_estudiante = e.id_estudiante
           INNER JOIN materias m ON a.id_materia = m.id_materia
           WHERE a.id_profesor = $idProfesor AND a.id_estudiante = $idEstudiante" ;


           $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

           if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
           // Imprimir la tabla
           echo "<table>";
           echo "<tr><th>Asistencia</th><th>Acción</th></tr>";

           while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
           $idAsistencia = $fila['id_asistencia_temp'];
           $estadoAsistencia = $fila['estado_asistencia'];

           // Imprimir cada fila de la tabla
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>$estadoAsistencia</td>";
           echo "<td>";
           echo "<input type='radio' name='estado_asistencia$idAsistencia' value='Presente' " . ($estadoAsistencia == 'Presente' ? 'checked' : '') . "> Presente ";
           echo "<input type='radio' name='estado_asistencia$idAsistencia' value='Ausente' " . ($estadoAsistencia == 'Ausente' ? 'checked' : '') . "> Ausente";
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td><button onclick='actualizarAsistencia(\"$idAsistencia\")'>Actualizar</button></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
           }

           echo "</table>";
           } else {
           echo "No se encontraron registros de asistencia para el estudiante seleccionado.";
           }

           mysqli_close($conexion);
           ?>
           <script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

           <script src="/home2/augebout/public_html/ctpjosema.com/script.js"></script>


       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Saludos. Verifica que cargas el archivo **JavaScript** donde tienes declarada esa función; también que este escrito de manera identifica (es decir respetando mayúsculas/minúsculas); en el código que compartes no aparece la función que marca error.

Comment: He intentado de 2 formas, mandando a llamar al archivo, con la siguiente linea:      <script src="/home2/augebout/public_html/ctpjosema.com/script.js"></script> y la segunda, poniendo la funcion en ese mismo lugar donde esta la linea anterior.

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias por las indicaciones.
Ya puse la línea dentro del **head** y sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: Saludos @RobertoLeOr, Ya verifiqué que los nombres sean iguales, y está correcto.  ya agregué la funcion al código. Gracias!